# How to create pkg installer on yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, pkgbuild

How to create pkg installer on yosemite.
I need an installer for java application which should do some file updates during installation. There is one for Xcode 4 but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to use for yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if something exists for Xcode directly. But I created a python script in Yosemite to utilize pkgbuild and productbuild like that of previous OSX versions, and utilized TKinter GUI, to get the component bundles(applications) to package up. Let me know if you need more implementation details.

Hope this helps.